# How to specify SBT main class on run

Tags: sbt

I want to be able to specify the main class to use when running a SBT project from the command line without having to select it from the list like on this example:

```
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list

Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

[1] sample.stream.BasicTransformation
[2] sample.stream.GroupLogFile
[3] sample.stream.TcpEcho
[4] sample.stream.WritePrimes

Enter number:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a specific class the command is:

```
sbt "runMain my.class.Name param1 param2"
```